# How do I remove the undo popup with the Registration Social Plugin?

Tags: facebook, plugins, dialog, registration

When using the Facebook Registration social plugin, the user is presented with an undo dialog after pressing the "Register" button. I've observed several sites that also use the Registration plugin that do not display this dialog, i.e. Car and Driver and Friend.ly.

Has anyone encountered this, and found the right box to check to disable the undo dialog behavior?

When looking at the returned files from Facebook, this parameter in registration.html seems to control this behavior:

FB.Registration.mustConfirm = false

I've tried the XML and older APIs, and have observed the same results. I'm looking for an official/supported solution to this problem, ideally, and not a JavaScript hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not currently available to all developers.  We may make it available more broadly, but right now it is limited to a few partners.